# Nginx redirect old PHP website URL's to new pages

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

We have a bunch of old backlinks from an old Joomla virtuemart installation, unfortunately any attempts to make a 301 redirect have failed. An example link is `https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=134&Itemid=1&vmcchk=1&Itemid=11%908`

Is there any way to match `/index.php` and redirect these to the new `/products` page?

I have tried, within the `server` block to add the following configuration:

```
rewrite ^/index(.*) https://www.example.com/products permanent;
```

Comment: Is the new website URI `/products` implemented using PHP? What happened when you added the `rewrite` statement?

Comment: The new website is JavaScript based, when I added the rewrite statement the old page was still being served with the virtuemart URL returning a 404 error.

Comment: So the `rewrite` statement is not doing anything, which could mean it's in the wrong place. Did you restart the server and clear the browser's cache after making changes? Test the configuration using `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) and ensure that the `rewrite` statement is present in the correct `server` block.